# How to avoid upper-case letters in the header?

Tags: koma-script, indexing

I've used two indexes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,headsepline,parskip=half-,index=totoc,BCOR=5mm,DIV=15]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=stichwortA,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisA,options=-s ./main]
\makeindex[name=stichwortB,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisB,columns=4,options=-s ./main]
\begin{document}
\printindex[stichwortA]
```

Unfortunately in the heading it's written `STICHWORT-VERZEICHNISA` with upper-case letters.

Can I change the definition in the preamble to get normal case letters as `Stichwort-VerzeichnisA`?

Comment: please make your example minimal and compilable. Is the index really needed here or would you see the same thing for any `\chapter\section...`? Or do you just want to change this behaviour for the index?

Comment: There is no heading since there aren't any `\index` commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option `headers` that can be set by `\indexsetup`:

```
\indexsetup{headers={\indexname}{\indexname}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=stichwortA,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisA]
\makeindex[name=stichwortB,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisB,columns=4]

\indexsetup{
  firstpagestyle=headings,% only to show the header in this example
  headers={\indexname}{\indexname}
}

\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
Text \index[stichwortA]{Test A}
\printindex[stichwortA]
\end{document}
```

The code above works also with the package `scrlayer-scrheadings`. Or you could also use the `scrlayer-scrheadings` option `markcase=noupper`.

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[automark,markcase=noupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=stichwortA,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisA]
\makeindex[name=stichwortB,title=Stichwort-VerzeichnisB,columns=4]

\indexsetup{
  firstpagestyle=scrheadings,% only to show the header in this example
}

\begin{document}
Text \index[stichwortA]{Test A}
\printindex[stichwortA]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice! With ``indexsetup`` it works. Adding ``\clearscrheadfoot`` before 
    ``\printindex[stichwortA]`` removes the headings. Is it possible to remove also the headsepline on this specific page?

Comment: Remove `firstpagestyle=...` from the code. I have inserted this option because there is only the first index page in my example.